# What are the conditions for a compact, convex set to be homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in the plane?

Tags: general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

A generalization of Brower's fixed point theorem says that any continuous map from compact, convex set in the plane $K$ to itself, $f:K \to K$, must have a fixed point.

It is easy to see that any set homeomorphic to the closed unit disk must have a Brower fixed point theorem. However, the above generalization includes a wider array of allowed sets than just those homeomorphic to the closed unit disk. For instance, it includes the set $\{0\} \times [0,1]$.

In some sense, that is not surprising as that just reduces to a lower dimensional case. But this makes me wonder, what additional sets are being added? Is it just lower dimensional cases? In other words, what are the conditions for a compact, convex set to be homeomorphic to the closed unit ball? Purely that it is 2 dimensional?

Comment: But $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ **is** homeomorphic to the closed unit disk...

Comment: A compact convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball if and only if it has nonempty interior.

Comment: The generalization you mention is actually stated and proved for Euclidean spaces of any dimension.

Comment: I'm confused about the homeomorphism... I can't see how there can be continuous bijective map. There might be a homotopy, I think. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DanielFischer, that would be equivalent to there being three non collinear points in the set, correct?

Comment: Right. Generally, a nonempty compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball in the affine subspace it spans.

Comment: I don't think the closed unit disk can be homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. There would be a homeomorphism between an open interval and an open ball. But then there would be a homeomorphism between R1 and R2, which is impossible.

Comment: @abnry, another way to see it is that it is possible to remove a single point from $[0, 1]$ so that it becomes disconnected.  On the other hand, this is impossible with the closed unit disk.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, indeed, every nonempty compact convex subset of $R^n$ is homeomorphic to the closed unit ball of suitable dimension.

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478921/is-the-closure-of-an-open-bounded-convex-set-already-a-ball/479197#479197). In the answer I was using the assumption that the set in question is symmetric and has nonempty interior; in your case it need not be symmetric so you use an [asymmetric norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_norm) $p(x)$ instead. The point is that every convex subset $C$ with nonempty interior in the $n$-dimensional affine space $A^n$ is [absorbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set) with respect to the origin that belongs to the interior of $C$ and, hence, defines a norm on the corresponding vector space. If you have a nonempty  convex subset $C\subset R^n$ with empty interior, then $C$ will have nonempty interior in its affine hull, i.e. the smallest affine subspace of $R^n$ containing $C$, see for instance, Rahul's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/why-does-a-convex-set-have-the-same-interior-points-as-its-closure).